# Continuity of a recursive piece-wise function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, recursion, piecewise-continuity

I'm a student studying math, and I'm going through some old exam problems and I have come across a set of questions that ask me to decide where a given piece-wise function is continuous. The function in question is.

$$f(x)= \begin{cases} 
      |x-1| & \text{if }x \geq 0  \\
      f(-x) & \text{if }x <0 \\
   \end{cases}
$$

This function naturally is causing me much confusion. The function seems it will trail of into a infinite string of functions in functions. However If I had to guess its continuity I'd hazard intuitively there appears to be no reason $f(x)$ is not defined across $\mathbb{R}$. Am I right to think this? Is there a rigorous theorem I should be using? And how do I manage this recursive second condition?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Does it really "trail of into a infinite string of functions"?  It strikes me that it's an even function, and that you know how it behaves on the positive reals. Can you draw its graph?

Comment: Just reflect the positive portion of the function about y-axis to get the negative half. Since the positive half on it's own is continuous, and hence it's reflection is continuous, all you have to check is the boundary point at $x=0$